# Cell Modem LAI number makeup

Tags: modem

Not sure if this is the right forum for this question, if not please let me know.

To my understanding the LAI number for cell modems is the concatinated version of the 3-digit MCC plus the 2- or 3- digit MNC.  Now my question is a two parter:

1. Am I correct in my assumption that the LAI is the concatinated version of the MCC and MNC?
2. If I am correct, how is the number broken up?  For example, if we have two LAI numbers, "123456" and "78910" how would they be broken down into the MCC and MNC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MCC is always the first three digits in the LAI.  This means that in the given examples:

MCC = 123

MNC = 456

and

MCC = 789

MNC = 10